# How to zip a file to STDOUT with zipfile?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, python-zipfile

I have a program that creates a zip file containing a couple of files using [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html). It takes an output filename as argument, but if no file or `-` is given, it should write to STDOUT. But if I pass `sys.stdout` as file parameter to ZipFile, it gives me the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 775, in __init__
    self._start_disk = self.fp.tell()
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek
```

Here's my code:

```
import zipfile, sys

def myopen(name, mode='r'):
    if name is not None:
        try: return open(name, mode)
        except EnvironmentError as e:
            print >> sys.stderr, '%s: %s' % (name, e.strerror)
            sys.exit(3)
    elif mode == 'r': return sys.stdin
    elif mode in 'aw': return sys.stdout
    else: return None

outfile = None

# build the files ...
files = {'file1': 'Here is an example file.\n', 'file2': 'Some more ...'}

with myopen(outfile, 'w') as f, zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, True) as zf:
    for name, content in files.iteritems(): zf.writestr(name, content)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: @G_M I added it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot zip directly to stdout, because it's necessary to go back in the output file and update file info in the zip directory.  Assuming the total size isn't too large, you could zip to an in-memory file object (`StringIO`/`BytesIO`), then dump that to stdout when you're done.

Comment: Writing to a stream was implemented in python 3.5, according to the doc. You could try back-porting that, or try [zipstream](https://github.com/allanlei/python-zipstream) which I think works for python 2.7 though I havent tried.